# Rspec matching ActiveRecord result sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, controller, tdd

UPDATED: I realise now that I've been misreading the diff, and I have a string or symbol on one side of the comparison. Still unsure how I should be putting the expectation in this test however..

I'm new to Rspec and TDD in general, and I've run into this problem. I have a controller that does this:

```
def index
  @users = User.page(params[:page])
end
```

(I'm using Kaminara to paginate)

And a spec:

```
describe "when the user DOES have admin status" do

  login_admin_user
  it "should allow the user access to the complete user list page" do
    get :index
    response.response_code.should == 200
  end

  describe "and views the /users page" do
    before(:each) do 
      User.stub(:page) {[ mock_model(User), mock_model(User), mock_model(User) ]}
    end

    it "should show all users" do
    get :index  
    assigns (:users).should =~ User.page
    end
  end

end
```

The spec fails with the following:

```
Failure/Error: assigns (:users).should =~ User.page
   expected: [#<User:0x5da86a8 @name="User_1004">, #<User:0x5d9c90c @name="User_1005">, #<User:0x5d93ef6 @name="User_1006">]
        got: :users (using =~)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,4 +1,2 @@
   -[#<User:0x5da86a8 @name="User_1004">,
   - #<User:0x5d9c90c @name="User_1005">,
   - #<User:0x5d93ef6 @name="User_1006">]
   +:users
```

Those result sets look identical. Why does this spec fail? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the space after `assigns`. It's comparing the symbol `:users` to your list. Change it to:

```
assigns(:users).should =~ User.page
```

And just a note on how to read Rspec failures. The part after `expected`, is what you gave to `should`, whereas the part after `got` is the value your code actually produced. So it's clear from the report that the result sets were not identical.

Comment: Yes, that's cracked it. Thanks!